# python list into dict

Tags: python, list

Here is my issue.

I have a list like this (out of a .txt file I have already assigned to a list element):

```
sharenames = ['VIAB:Viacom Inc.', 'DLTR:Dollar Tree Inc.', 'AAL:American Airlines Group Inc.', 'ROST:Ross Stores Inc.', 'VRTX:Vertex Pharmaceuticals Incorporated', 'WDC:Western Digital Corp', 'NCLH:Norwegian Cruise Line Holdings Ltd', 'SWKS:Skyworks Solutions Inc.', 'BBBY:Bed Bath & Beyond Inc.', 'BIDU:Baidu Inc (ADR)', 'ENDP:Endo International plc', '"FRA:DBK":Deutsche Bank AG', '"FRA:FME":Fresenius Medical Care AG & Co. KGaA', '"FRA:DAI":Daimler AG']
```

I want to create a dictionary I can access access like

```
wertA = sharenames["FRA:FME"]  # as an example
```

or

```
wertA = sharenames[ROST]  # as an example
```

After some hours of try and error I hope you can help me out.

Comment: You need to be clear about the format of the list. Is it true that, for each string in the list, everything before the last colon is the abbreviation, and everything after that last colon is the full name? And you want the abbreviations as keys in the dictionary and the full names as the values? Finally, please tell us at least one thing that you tried in those "some hours" of try and error.

Comment: You should clean the data first. How did you get it? The double-quotes make it harder to parse the list correctly.

Comment: Hi Rory, I tryed suggested solutions like import the data another way, JSON, etc, but as I am new to python this takes some time.

Comment: Hi Vedang, you are right. sorry.

Comment: I imported a text file where every pair is in the next line. Your solution helped me out! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mapping from a list of tuples:

```
data =  ['VIAB:Viacom Inc.', 'DLTR:Dollar Tree Inc.', 'AAL:American Airlines Group Inc.', 'ROST:Ross Stores Inc.', 'VRTX:Vertex Pharmaceuticals Incorporated', 'WDC:Western Digital Corp', 'NCLH:Norwegian Cruise Line Holdings Ltd', 'SWKS:Skyworks Solutions Inc.', 'BBBY:Bed Bath & Beyond Inc.', 'BIDU:Baidu Inc (ADR)', 'ENDP:Endo International plc', '"FRA:DBK":Deutsche Bank AG', '"FRA:FME":Fresenius Medical Care AG & Co. KGaA', '"FRA:DAI":Daimler AG']
mapping = dict(entry.rsplit(':', 1) for entry in data)
```

Notice I'm using `string.rsplit` to the maximum of a single split (second argument). Also, this assumes you have no colons in your values.

Items in mapping:

```
ENDP -> Endo International plc
WDC -> Western Digital Corp
VIAB -> Viacom Inc.
AAL -> American Airlines Group Inc.
DLTR -> Dollar Tree Inc.
BBBY -> Bed Bath & Beyond Inc.
"FRA:DAI" -> Daimler AG
VRTX -> Vertex Pharmaceuticals Incorporated
"FRA:FME" -> Fresenius Medical Care AG & Co. KGaA
SWKS -> Skyworks Solutions Inc.
NCLH -> Norwegian Cruise Line Holdings Ltd
ROST -> Ross Stores Inc.
"FRA:DBK" -> Deutsche Bank AG
BIDU -> Baidu Inc (ADR)
```

To clean keys from double-quotes you can do:

```
clean_mapping = {k.replace('"',''): v for k, v in mapping}
```

Comment: Does that work for list items that have more than one colon, such as 'FRA:DBK'?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split every item at the ":". The following code makes the desired dictionary:

```
sharenames = {}
for item in lst:
    sharenames[":".join(item.split(":")[:-1])] = item.split(":")[-1]
```

Example: `sharenames["ENDP"] >>> 'Endo International plc'`

Comment: Does that work for strings that have more than one colon, such the one starting 'FRA:FME'?

Comment: I edited so it does, as long as there are no colons in the full name

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
sharenames = ['VIAB:Viacom Inc.', 'DLTR:Dollar Tree Inc.', 'AAL:American Airlines Group Inc.', 'ROST:Ross Stores Inc.', 'VRTX:Vertex Pharmaceuticals Incorporated', 'WDC:Western Digital Corp', 'NCLH:Norwegian Cruise Line Holdings Ltd', 'SWKS:Skyworks Solutions Inc.', 'BBBY:Bed Bath & Beyond Inc.', 'BIDU:Baidu Inc (ADR)', 'ENDP:Endo International plc', '"FRA:DBK":Deutsche Bank AG', '"FRA:FME":Fresenius Medical Care AG & Co. KGaA', '"FRA:DAI":Daimler AG']

# Conversions;
sharenames = (sharename.rsplit(':',1) for sharename in sharenames)
sharenames = ((sharename[0].strip('"'),sharename[1]) for sharename in sharenames)
sharenames = dict(sharenames)

print sharenames['ROST']
print sharenames["FRA:FME"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
for e in sharenames:
    t = tuple(string.rsplit(e,':', 1))
    d[re.sub('\"','',t[0])] = t[1]

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

ENDP Endo International plc

WDC Western Digital Corp

VIAB Viacom Inc.

FRA:DBK Deutsche Bank AG

AAL American Airlines Group Inc.

DLTR Dollar Tree Inc.

BBBY Bed Bath & Beyond Inc.

VRTX Vertex Pharmaceuticals Incorporated

SWKS Skyworks Solutions Inc.

NCLH Norwegian Cruise Line Holdings Ltd

ROST Ross Stores Inc.

FRA:DAI Daimler AG

FRA:FME Fresenius Medical Care AG & Co. KGaA

BIDU Baidu Inc (ADR)